# What's wrong - expected class-name before '{' token

Tags: c++

What's wrong in this code ? I get **[Error] expected class-name before '{' token** (Pralka.h line 14 )

i know there are lots of similar questions here. I've googled too but I can't get over it. So I would like to show you my code..

I wrote this very simple code to train myself on inheritance and virtual functions..

**main.cpp:**

```
   #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <string>

    #include "AGD.h"

    using namespace std;

    int main() {        
    Pralka p1("polar", 1250); 
    AGD *A;
    A = &p1; 
    }
```

**AGD.h:**

```
#ifndef AGD_H
#define AGD_H

#include <iostream>

#include "Pralka.h"

class AGD {

    private:

        static int liczba_sprzetow;

    public:

        AGD(){
            liczba_sprzetow++;
        }

        ~AGD(){
            liczba_sprzetow--;
        }


        static int  get_liczba_sprzetow() {
            return liczba_sprzetow;
        }

        virtual double get_cena() {
        }

};

#endif
```

**Pralka.h:**

```
#ifndef PRALKA_H
#define PRALKA_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>



using namespace std;

class Pralka : public AGD
 {
    private:

        string marka;
        double cena;

    public:

        Pralka(string m, double c): marka(m), cena(c){
        }

        Pralka(){
        }
        ~Pralka(){
        }


        string get_marka() const{
            return marka;
        }

        double get_cena() const{
            return cena;
        }

        Pralka& operator=(const Pralka& Q){
         marka=Q.marka;
        cena=Q.cena;
        }

};

#endif
```

I get also **[Error] cannot convert 'Pralka*' to 'AGD*' in assignment** but why? I don't understand (main.cpp line 29).

Comment: Indent your code for a better world.

Comment: I assume, the compiler also prints out the file and line number?

Comment: You've got your includes the wrong way round - pralca.h should `#include "agd.h"` not the other way round

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`AGD.h` is including `Pralka.h`, but it should be the other way round (`Pralka.h` should be including `AGD.h`).

The reason is that `Pralka` needs to see the `AGD` declaration to inherit from it. `AGD` doesn't need to see the `Pralka` declaration.

Comment: Now I get **[Error] 'Pralka' was not declared in this scope** in main.cpp.   

In main.cpp which file include ?

Comment: You need to include `Pralka.h` in `main.cpp` as well. You can safely include `AGD.h` in there as well, although it's not strictly necessary. The important things are: (1) any usage must be able to see the declaration, and (2) don't end up with two different headers including each other.